# Dynamic table creation with ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, json

I want to generate dynamic table with dynamic table header and row/columns according to json object comes from webapi.

[image]

Here are examples of json object which comes every time different.

```js
[
  {"Country":"Australia","Toner Quantity":8},
  {"Country":"China","Toner Quantity":6},
  {"Country":"India","Toner Quantity":11},
  {"Country":"South Korea","Toner Quantity":1}
]
```

and some time it comes like

```js
[
  {"CustomerName":"FORD","Australia":0,"China":2,"India":0,"South Korea":0},
  {"CustomerName":"ICICI PRUDENTIAL","Australia":0,"China":0,"India":5,"South Korea":0},
  {"CustomerName":"Kimberly Clark","Australia":0,"China":0,"India":0,"South Korea":1},
  {"CustomerName":"McDonalds","Australia":1,"China":0,"India":0,"South Korea":0},
  {"CustomerName":"Novartis","Australia":1,"China":0,"India":0,"South Korea":0},
  {"CustomerName":"Origin Energy","Australia":3,"China":0,"India":0,"South Korea":0}
]
```

So I have tried but not able to achieve dynamic table with headers and row/columns

my html code like

```html
<table class="table striped">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th ng-repeat="th in dataconfigureListData.previewData">{{th}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row" data-ng-repeat="previewData in dataconfigureListData.previewData">
      <td> {{previewData.Country}}</td>
      <td> {{previewData['Total Toner Qty']}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: So far what you done ? your code

Comment: where is? , your tried code

Comment: What is `dataconfigureListData`?

Comment: $scope.dataconfigureListData.previewData= data.ResponseData; it stores data which coming from web api

Comment: Ans what `{{ dataconfigureListData.previewData | json }}` prints?

Comment: [ { "CustomerName": "FORD", "Australia": 0, "China": 2, "India": 0, "South Korea": 0 }, { "CustomerName": "ICICI PRUDENTIAL", "Australia": 0, "China": 0, "India": 5, "South Korea": 0 }, { "CustomerName": "Kimberly Clark", "Australia": 0, "China": 0, "India": 0, "South Korea": 1 }, { "CustomerName": "McDonalds", "Australia": 1, "China": 0, "India": 0, "South Korea": 0 }, { "CustomerName": "Novartis", "Australia": 1, "China": 0, "India": 0, "South Korea": 0 }, { "CustomerName": "Origin Energy", "Australia": 3, "China": 0, "India": 0, "South Korea": 0 } ]

Comment: In this case your code is correct.

Comment: but i am not able to display header like wise

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this by using an `ng-repeat` inside another. And also, use the first line to render the headers.

> **Note on `ngRepeat`:** For some reason, **`angularjs@1.4.0` previous versions sorted the keys alphabetically when using `ng-repeat` by `key in object`**. A simple way to fix that is upgrading to `angularjs@^1.4.0` which is where they fixed it.
>
> **Announce of this change by angular docs:**
>
> *You need to be aware that the JavaScript specification does not define the order of keys returned for an object. (To mitigate this in Angular 1.3 the ngRepeat directive used to sort the keys alphabetically.)*
>
> *Version 1.4 removed the alphabetic sorting. We now rely on the order returned by the browser when running for key in myObj. It seems that browsers generally follow the strategy of providing keys in the order in which they were defined, although there are exceptions when keys are deleted and reinstated. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Cross-browser_issues*
>
> Ref.: [Iterating over object properties](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/docs/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

The following snippet implements this solution.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.myArray = [
      { "CustomerName": "FORD", "Australia": 0, "China": 2, "India": 0, "South Korea": 0 },
      { "CustomerName": "ICICI PRUDENTIAL", "Australia": 0, "China": 0, "India": 5, "South Korea": 0 },
      { "CustomerName": "Kimberly Clark", "Australia": 0, "China": 0, "India": 0, "South Korea": 1 },
      { "CustomerName": "McDonalds", "Australia": 1, "China": 0, "India": 0, "South Korea": 0 },
      { "CustomerName": "Novartis", "Australia": 1, "China": 0, "India": 0, "South Korea": 0 },
      { "CustomerName": "Origin Energy", "Australia": 3, "China": 0, "India": 0, "South Korea": 0 }
    ];
  });

angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td,
th {
  padding: 2px 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<table ng-controller="myController" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th ng-repeat="(key, val) in myArray[0]">{{ key }}</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="row in myArray">
    <td ng-repeat="column in row">
      {{ column }}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

#### The example bellow implements sorting columns dynamically by clicking on the column's header and also with reverse by clicking again on the selected column

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myController', function($scope) {
  
    $scope.sortByColumn = 'CustomerName';
    $scope.sortByReverse = false;
    $scope.sortBy = function(column) {
      if (column === $scope.sortByColumn) {
        $scope.sortByReverse = !$scope.sortByReverse;
      } else {
        $scope.sortByReverse = false;
      }

      $scope.sortByColumn = column;
    };
    
    $scope.getSortColumn = function () {
      // it has to be like this, otherwize, the `orderBy sortByColumn`
      // breaks for special names like "South Korea"
      return '"' + $scope.sortByColumn + '"';
    };
    
    $scope.myArray = [
      { "CustomerName": "FORD", "Australia": 0, "China": 2, "India": 0, "South Korea": 0 },
      { "CustomerName": "ICICI PRUDENTIAL", "Australia": 0, "China": 0, "India": 5, "South Korea": 0 },
      { "CustomerName": "Kimberly Clark", "Australia": 0, "China": 0, "India": 0, "South Korea": 1 },
      { "CustomerName": "McDonalds", "Australia": 1, "China": 0, "India": 0, "South Korea": 0 },
      { "CustomerName": "Novartis", "Australia": 1, "China": 0, "India": 0, "South Korea": 0 },
      { "CustomerName": "Origin Energy", "Australia": 3, "China": 0, "India": 0, "South Korea": 0 }
    ];
  });

angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 2px 4px;
}

[ng-click] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<table ng-controller="myController" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th ng-repeat="(key, val) in myArray[0]" ng-click="sortBy(key)">
      {{ key }}
      <span ng-if="sortByColumn === key">{{ sortByReverse ? '▲' : '▼' }}</span>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="row in myArray | orderBy : getSortColumn() : sortByReverse">
    <td ng-repeat="column in row">
      {{ column }}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Perfect example of dynamic data in ng-repeat.

Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: @Lenilson de CastroI have used as you explained then I am getting the table but the column is coming alphabetically. if we look at answer for me it is columns order as `Australia, China, CustomerName, India, South Korea`

Comment: @charantej what do you mean by "the column is coming alphabetically"? This model assumes the of objects to be uniform, that is, all objects in array must have the same structure and order. `{ CustomerName: string, Australia: number, China: number, India: number, South Korea: number }`.

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro For me, if I pass same array table header comes in this order  `Australia, China, CustomerName, India, South Korea`

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro I have used the same code in answer and got like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5KQC.png

Comment: @charantej Holy! Have you changed anything in the code? Can you provide a fiddle reproducing that for me? Which browser are you using?

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro I have created the jsflddle Please look at it https://jsfiddle.net/CharanTej/qkxmgg33/

Comment: @charantej Well! For some reason, `angularjs@1.3.12` sorts the keys when using `ng-repeat` by `key in object`. A simple way to fix that is upgrading to `angularjs@1.4.x` which is where they fixed it. I'll add a note on that.

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro I have given textbox for that value inside ng-repeat and added save button but how to get that scope. please look at this https://jsfiddle.net/CharanTej/qkxmgg33/3/

Comment: @charantej I've changed the access level from `column` to the array directly `myArray[$parent.$index][key]` check this out https://jsfiddle.net/qkxmgg33/4/

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro If i use index in repeat then dir-paginate is not working (by click on any other page number also only first page data is showing ) Please take a look at my total code https://plnkr.co/edit/73Wf1m6aXkaitEjfaoKK?p=preview

Comment: @charantej use `ng-model="myArray[(__default__currentPage-1)*ItemsPerPageCount + $parent.$index][key]"` instead. Also, the previous questions you've made have nothing to do with my answer, it's a different tech and a different problem, if you have more doubts about other problems and techs, please make a new question because this one is not related anymore.

Comment: Is it possible to add sorting ?

Comment: @itsme yes, simply add the `orderBy` filter: `ng-repeat="row in myArray | orderBy : 'CustomerName'"`. I've updated the answer, check it out.

Comment: @Lenilson de Castro Dynamically we need to use sorting .. how can we achieve this

Comment: @itsme I don't know what you mean by that. Can you elaborate? What's dynamic in the question? The column you're sorting by? You need to dynamically set the column it'd be sorting the records, is that correct?

Comment: @itsme I've added an example doing that at the bottom of my answer, expand the snippet to run and have fun :{D

Answer (score 0):

The logic is to get the header by iterating on the first object props using `Object.keys`.

To get only the values from to the cells itself you can do `ng-repeat` with `(key, value) in some_obj`.

Here is a full example:

```js
angular.module('app', []).
controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data1 = [
    {"Country":"Australia","Toner Quantity":8},
    {"Country":"China","Toner Quantity":6},
    {"Country":"India","Toner Quantity":11},
    {"Country":"South Korea","Toner Quantity":1}
  ];

  $scope.data2 = [
    {"CustomerName":"FORD","Australia":0,"China":2,"India":0,"South Korea":0},
    {"CustomerName":"ICICI PRUDENTIAL","Australia":0,"China":0,"India":5,"South Korea":0},
    {"CustomerName":"Kimberly Clark","Australia":0,"China":0,"India":0,"South Korea":1},
    {"CustomerName":"McDonalds","Australia":1,"China":0,"India":0,"South Korea":0},
    {"CustomerName":"Novartis","Australia":1,"China":0,"India":0,"South Korea":0},
    {"CustomerName":"Origin Energy","Australia":3,"China":0,"India":0,"South Korea":0}
  ];

  $scope.getHeaders = function(arr) {
    return Object.keys(arr[0]);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td ng-repeat="header in getHeaders(data1)">{{header}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in data1">
      <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in row">{{value}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <hr />
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td ng-repeat="header in getHeaders(data2)">{{header}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in data2">
      <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in row">{{value}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

i'm using angular 1.6

[image: dynamic table header and according values.]

Here marked columns are dynamic as well as its values.
My table structures are below.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>Doctor</th>
           <th>Target</th>
           <th ng-repeat="brand in doctorTargets.brands">{|| brand.name ||}</th>
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in doctorTargets.doctorTargets">
           <td>{|| item.doctorName ||}</td>
           <td>{|| item.target ||}</td>
           <td ng-repeat="brand in item.brands">{||brand.target||</td>                                    
        </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: in your example, item.doctorName and item.target are fixed key value but in my case that's value also be dynamic

Comment: @Dixit in my example i placed and said what i did for dynamic column gerneration. If you need something different then skip it. But my code is functional as it was meant to be. Did you found any error in my code?

Comment: I clearly mention that I want to generate a dynamic table with dynamic table header and row/columns according to JSON object comes from webapi. but you don't provide the right solution for the dynamic table header and row/columns.

Comment: In my post "brand.name" are dynamic table header and "brand.target" are dynamic accordingly.