# dynamic table row generation using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs, mongodb

my problem is similar to thread

> [Dynamic table creation with ng-repeat in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40525417/dynamic-table-creation-with-ng-repeat-in-angularjs)

JSON looks like this

> { 
>           "id": "String",
>           "marks" : 
>                   {
>                      "nummin":"integer"
>                      "nummax":"integer"
>                      "subjectname": "string",
>                       }
>       }

Just there will be an additional feature user is going to enter no of rows which need to be generated and then the table will be generated according to dynamic JSON file which will be fetched from the database. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Tell us what the JSON file looks like and give us an idea about the table structure. With this information i can just refer to [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

Comment: json looks like this >{ 
        "id": "String",
        "marks" : 
                {
                   "nummin":"integer"
                   "nummax":"integer"
                   "subjectname": "string",
                    }
    }

Comment: Ok. The user should enter a number of rows to be displayed. Is this number an index of your marks section? Is this an amount of rows? Should the marks section be displayed inside a parent table?

Comment: see the table will be like user enters the no of fields then that no of rows appears he enters the details in the table then the data gets saved in the database in above mentioned structured JSON file.And of course  the table will be empty initially then the details gets saved .

Comment: I now get an idea about what you want to do. Let me think about it and ill provide you an answer in a short time.

Comment: yeah, the number is a no. of rows and yes marks will be displayed inside the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out [this JS-Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dhp1ya2u/).

```
let app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', ($scope) => {

    $scope.numberOfRows = 0;
    $scope.data = [];

    $scope.$watch('data', () => {
        console.log($scope.data);
    }, true);

}]);
app.filter('range', function () {
    return function (input, total) {
        total = parseInt(total, 10);

        for (let i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            input.push(i);
        }
        return input;
    };
});


<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <input type="number" ng-model="numberOfRows" />
    <br />
    <table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <th>nummin</th><th>nummax</th><th>...</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="i in [] | range:numberOfRows">
        <td>
        <input type="number" ng-model="data[i].nummin" />
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type="number" ng-model="data[i].nummax" />
        </td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your help but in this thead is also appearing n no of times but I want it to appear only once that is it is fixed how can I modify it.

Comment: this is my fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/fuymqf8z/2/ kindly see it once

Comment: I am not able to understand your problem. Do you mean the index or the table header appering more than once?

Comment: sry for my language it just I am a bit messed up....theader is appearing more than once.Have a look at the fiddle which I have included you will understand my problem. and your solution is not working also when I am using it in my code.

Comment: you can remove the `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` to use a normal `ng-repeat` on one `<tr>`. See [this JS-Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dhp1ya2u/2/)

Comment: oh!! Thanks for your help.I have fixed it already. Thank you so much.