# How To Transclude Table Row Into AngularJs Component

Tags: html, angularjs, components, angularjs-ng-transclude, transclusion

Iv been trying to create an angularJS component for constructing a dynamic html table from a provided array.
The components template includes some ng-transclude directives as 'placeholders'/slots for templates provided by the component consumer.

Is it possible to transclude a `<tr>` template (with nested `<th>`), to be used inside the table `<thead>`?

I have tried using all variations for transclution:
`transclude: true`, `transclude: 'element'`
and `transclude: { header: 'header'}`
(the third option seems as the most suitable, as I will eventually required multiple elements to be transcluded).

Component:

```js
app.component("virtualTable", {
  bindings: {
    someArray: "<"
  },
  transclude: {
    header: "header"
  },
  templateUrl: () => {
    return "/app/components/virtual-table.component.html";
  });
```

Component Template:

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr ng-transclude="header"></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in vt.someArray">
        ...another place for transclution...
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Consuming HTML (component declaration):

```html
<virtual-table some-array="vm.personList">
    <header>
        <th>First Column</th>
        <th>Second Column<th>
    </header>
</virtual-table>
```

I excpect the compiled DOM to look like this:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Column</th>
            <th>Second Column</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
...
```

But instead I get the innerHTML of the transcluded element (header) as Text:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr ng-transclude="header">
            <header class="ng-scope">
                First Column
                Second Column
        </tr>
    </header>
...
```

I Suspect the browser (chrome 76) to somehow strip the `<tr>` tags from the transcluded element before it is being provided to the component (as it illegal us to use `<tr>` outside of a `<table>`).
I would like to maintain an html table structure.
Is The Any Way to Solve This?

Comment: Maybe it will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40525417/dynamic-table-creation-with-ng-repeat-in-angularjs
It's not a component, but it's a dynamic table. You can copy the idea and tailor it to your needs.

Comment: Toda (thanks) @MiriGold, However the construction of the table has to be within a component (or directive) for the purpose of reusability. This component is meant to be used throughout a huge web application (currently about 400 unique pages) as a replacement for kendo (grid) library. For this reason, I must keep it as modular/generic as possible. For this to happen, the consumer should be able to provide the table head row (among other parts of the table) via transclusion.